# jQuery: Select Iterated elements with class A-i and B-i only when all A-i also have B-i, or don't select any at all

Tags: jquery, loops

The code below has three rows of divs.

Using jQuery, how would I search through each row for A-# and B-#, making changes only to divs within rows with matching elements (in this case, only row 2 divs).

```css
.A-0 {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 49px;
}

.A-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 49px;
}

.A-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 49px;
}
```

```html
/* row 1 */
<div class="A-0 B-0"></div>
<div class="A-0"></div>
<div class="A-0 B-0"></div>

/* row 2 */
<div class="A-1 B-1"></div>
<div class="A-1 B-1"></div>

/* row 3 */
<div class="A-2"></div>
<div class="A-2 B-2"></div>
<div class="A-2 B-2"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand " in this case, only row 2 divs" what case, you said  i-# and A-#, how can that select row two items? And what are rows? They are not separated anyhow in HTML.

Comment: @ikiK Thank you for your comment. By row, I loosely mean the next linebreak (the linebreak would be caused by the widths reaching 100%). All row two items all have both i-# and A-#, unlike row 1 and row 3. So the selection needed would skip over divs within row 1 and 3, and not apply anything to them.

Comment: And how exactly are you planing to target "row" to compare items inside? Using line breaks and width? Your logic is wrong...

Comment: @ikiK The question is asking how to target class A-i and B-i only when A-i also has B-i, where "i" is the current row number.  Div widths totaling 100% are considered one row. Row 2 divs would be the only divs meeting this condition in this case if you look at the classes. Targeting these divs involves jQuery, which is the request of the question. Thanks! I appreciate you.

Comment: "how to target class A-i and B-i only when A-i also has B-i,"  what B are you talking about now?

Comment: By B, I am talking about the second class "i-1, i-2, and i-3" sometimes paired with A-i. A and B, or first and second.

Comment: @ikiK I updated the question with an edit with regards to the confusion of A and B, where "i-#" wasn't originally "B-#" (B-i). Thank you.

Comment: My answer is working under current class setup any changes to HTML may break it. And you will need to adjust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('div').each(function(index, value) {
  //for each div
  var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
  //extract classes for curent
  var class1 = classes[0];
  //class1 = A-#
  var class2 = classes[1];
  //class2 = B-#
  var numeEl = $('div.' + class1).length;
  //Number off elements with class1 A-#
  var numeEl2 = $('div.' + class1 + '.' + class2).length;
  //Number off elements with class1 A-# AND class2 B-#
  $('div.' + class1).each(function(index, value) {
    //for each element div with class: A-#
    if (numeEl === numeEl2) {
      //if number of elements is matching
      $(this).css("color", "red")
      //do something
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.A-0 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.A-1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.A-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>

<div class="A-0 B-0">A-0 B-0</div>
<div class="A-0">A-0</div>
<div class="A-0 B-0">A-0 B-0</div>
<br>

<div class="A-1 B-1">A-1 B-1</div>
<div class="A-1 B-1">A-1 B-1</div>
<br>

<div class="A-2">A-2</div>
<div class="A-2 B-2">A-2 B-2</div>
<div class="A-2 B-2">A-2 B-2</div>
```